# "that represents" vs "representing"

Tags: grammar, verbs

Is either of these forms more accurate than the other, do they share the same implication?

A:

> A diagram that represents the movement of the ball.

B:

> A diagram representing the movement of the ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent. the second line is the **reduced relative clause** of the first line.

Comment: Thank you. My search terms were off enough that I couldn't quite get to reduced relative clause.

Comment: @plast1k I'd avoid the term 'reduced relative clause' since it's a misnomer. Relative clauses are virtually always finite, whereas the second example is non-finite. It has the same meaning as the first, of course, but it's syntactically different in that it's a gerund-participial clause, not a relative one.